# Is it haram to touch my nipple( I am a male teenager ) and slightly stimulate myself?

Tags: halal-haram

When I stay alone like the time of studying I automatically have thoughts like having sex with someone, these moments are very disturbing for me , I can't do any work then .( I am a male teenager).. If I just touch my nipples then I feel slightly excited, and I feel better then , but I don't touch my penis , so I don't musterbate...so is it okay to touch my nipple and slightly stimulate myself ? I don't think about sex ,just touch my nipples and it slightly stimulates me . That's it .

Answer (score 0):

It is very good to hear you do not masterbate. But Allah, forbids all acts of shamefulness:

Allah commands justice, the doing of good, and liberty to kith and kin, and **He forbids all shameful deeds**, and injustice and rebellion: He instructs you, that ye may receive admonition. (90) Fulfil the covenant of Allah when ye have entered into it, and break not your oaths after ye have confirmed them; indeed ye have made Allah your surety; for Allah knoweth all that ye do. (16:91)

Remember satan is everywhere and he commmads people to do shameful deeds. The advice in the quran is:

When satan assults you remember Allah, it will help. see verse below:

Indeed, those who fear (Allah) when touches them an evil thought from the Shaitaan, they remember (Allah) and then they (are) those who see (aright).(7:201)

Try to recite surah Baqara in your place of study. It is said, that the house surah baqara is read satan does not enter it for 3 days. It is long but since satan does not enter your house for 3 days you can read it over 3 days.

recite after fajr and magrib prayer:

La ilaha illallahu wahdahu la sharika lahu lahul mulku wa lahul hamdu wa huwa ‘ala kulli shay in qadir one hundred times you will be protected from Shaytan all day.

recite after fajr and magrib prayer the 3 Qul's X3 (i.e.112:1-4,113:1-5 and 114:1-6), 3 times spit blow on hand and wipe yourself from head to teo 3 times.

It can be taxing to ask someone to compeletly block unwanted thoughts, you cannot stop them but what you can do is not to prolog them yourself. You know when you are doing this. If you prolong the bad thought yourself, then you can make a solemn oath to Allah to couple this act to another act that will stop you from doing it for example:

1. read 200 nafl salat without break

2)fast 2 months without break

3. give 1000 pound in charity

If you do this your bad thoughts will very quickly vanish.

You must be strict in which ever rule you choose otherwise it will not work. These number work, but some people are weak so you can adjust them like 10 days fast instead, but try to get the balance right. And indeed it says in the Quran those who turn off evil with good:

and those who observe patience in order to seek the pleasure of their Lord and establish Salāh and spend secretly and openly from what We have given to them, and repel evil with good. Those are the ones for whom there is the ultimate abode, (13:22)

And there is more good news for those who believe and restain there souls from lowly desires:

And for such as had entertained the fear of standing before their Lord's (tribunal) and had restrained (their) soul from lower Desires, (79:40) Their Abode will be the Garden. (79:41)

stimulating yourself by touching you nipple, is an act of shamfulness. It is not a good idea to curb your bad thoughts with a bad act. But rather throught remeberance of Allah, seeking from Allah protection from shaytan and by turning it off with good deeds. And I also adive you to ask forgiveness for any sin of shamfulness.